# Trying to extract content from url in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the content of a webpage from a URL. I have already written the code but I think I have made a mistake in the regex part. When I run the code only the first line appears in the console. I am using `NetBeans`. Code that I already have:

```
private static String text;
public static void main(String[]args){
URL u;
  InputStream is = null;
  DataInputStream dis;
  String s;

  try {

     u = new URL("http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/AKT1 ");

     is = u.openStream();         

     dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));


     text="";
     while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
        text+=s;
     }

  } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {

     System.out.println("Ouch - a MalformedURLException happened.");
     mue.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);

  } catch (IOException ioe) {

     System.out.println("Oops- an IOException happened.");
     ioe.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);

  } finally {


      String pattern = "(?i)(<P>)(.+?)";
         System.out.println(text.split(pattern)[1]);

     try {
        is.close();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {

     }

  } 

}
}
```

Comment: Obligatory *regex is discouraged for parsing html, use html parsing APIs like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)* comment

Answer (score 2):

Consider extracting your webpage information through dedicated `html` parsing APIs like [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/). A simple example with your url to extract all the elements with the `<p>` tags would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/AKT1")
                    .get();
            Elements els = doc.select("p");

            for (Element el : els) {
                System.out.println(el.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Console:

```
On this page:
The official name of this gene is “v-akt murine thymoma viral oncogene homolog 1.”
AKT1 is the gene's official symbol. The AKT1 gene is also known by other names, listed below.
Read more about gene names and symbols on the About page.
The AKT1 gene provides instructions for making a protein called AKT1 kinase. This protein is found in various cell types throughout the body, where it plays a critical role in many signaling pathways. For example, AKT1 kinase helps regulate cell growth and division (proliferation), the process by which cells mature to carry out specific functions (differentiation), and cell survival. AKT1 kinase also helps control apoptosis, which is the self-destruction of cells when they become damaged or are no longer needed.
...
```

Comment: I have put this code and add the jsoup API too.but i think there are errors.

Comment: @stella there shouldn't be unless you are missing one or the other dependencies - works for me as is, what specific error do you get?

Comment: @popoFibo thank you its working fine. but now the problem is that the text should be saved in my database. How will i capture these text?

Comment: @stella sure, I am printing the data as I get it on to the console, you may try storing `el.text()` to a Java collection like a list or a simplistic String array and later iterate over it and insert to your tables OR a `StringBuilder` object

Comment: @PopoFibo like that String content[]=e1.text();

Comment: @stella like `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();for (Element el : els) {System.out.println(el.text());sb.append(el.text());}` and now you have all the data in `sb`. Try `System.out.println(sb.toString());` too

Comment: @PopoFibo i am using MySql database and in my table i have a field named links where the link is the one that we are using now. I have to extract the data as we did and display it on a text area on my application. Is this easy to do?

Comment: @stella yes the requirement is straightforward but extends the scope of this question a bit. Consider asking another question with specifics and you'd get enough traction to it too

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a new line character during string concatenation.
Append the `text` with a `new line` char after every line is read.

Change:

```
while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
    text+=s;
}
```

To:

```
while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
    text += s + "\n";
}
```

I suggest you use, `StringBulder` over `String` for building the final text.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
...
while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append( s ).append( "\n" );
}

...
System.out.println( text.toString() );
```