# get body content of html file in java

Tags: java, android, html, saxparser

i'm trying to get body content of html page.

suppose this html file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link href="../Styles/style.css" rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<p> text 1 </p>
<p> text 2 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

what i want is :

```
<p> text 1 </p> 
<p> text 2 </p>
```

so, i thought that using `SAXParser` would do that (if you know simpler way please tell me)

this is my code, but always i get **null** as body content:

```
private final String HTML_NAME_SPACE = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
private final String HTML_TAG = "html";
private final String BODY_TAG = "body";
public static void parseHTML(InputStream in, ContentHandler handler) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException
{
    if(in != null)
    {
        try
        {
            SAXParserFactory parseFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            XMLReader reader = parseFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(handler);
            InputSource source = new InputSource(in);
            source.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            reader.parse(source);
        }
        finally
        {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}

public ContentHandler constrauctHTMLContentHandler()
{
    RootElement root = new RootElement(HTML_NAME_SPACE, HTML_TAG);
    root.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() 
        {           
        @Override
        public void start(Attributes attributes) 
        {           
            String body = attributes.getValue(BODY_TAG);
            Log.d("html parser", "body: " + body);
        }
    });
return root.getContentHandler();
}
```

then

```
parseHTML(inputStream, constrauctHTMLContentHandler()); // inputStream is html file as stream
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Easier way - consider [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for html parsing, refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043592/trying-to-extract-content-from-url-in-java/22043838#22043838)

Comment: Have you checked which `attributes` you get in the `start` method? If I remember correctly, the callback will get called for every starting element.

Comment: @PopoFibo: since i'm not familiar with jsoup i prefer to not using it unless i have to

Comment: @Smutje: i'mt not sure i fully understand you, but `attributes.getValue(BODY_TAG);` specifies that i want body.

Comment: @mehdok I'm working on a non-jsoup answer for you, but having difficulty with some of the dependencies, particularly *RootElement* and *StartElementListener*.  Could you paste the imports you are using?

Comment: @TJamesBoone: i'm coding for android: 
`import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;

import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.sax.Element;
import android.sax.RootElement;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.util.Log;`

Comment: @mehdok Question:  Why does your method, `public ContentHandler constrauctHTMLContentHandler()`, not return anything?  It won't compile; did you leave out a line?

Comment: @TJamesBoone: the SAXParser tut on ibm suggest this way. actually i think this line `reader.parse(source);` parse the html and cause `start(Attributes attributes);`get called. but since it's my first experience using SAXParser maybe there is some mistake in my code.
but `Log.d("html parser", "body: " + body);` print the string, so i think it get called.

Comment: @mehdok It doesn't matter what `public ContentHandler constrauctHTMLContentHandler()` is calling or what it is trying to do; if it declares that it will return an object of type ContentHandler and then does not have any return statement, the code will not compile and your program will never start.  Can you double-check the code you have for this method and make sure it's the same as what you pasted in your question?

Comment: sorry, you are right, i forgot the line `return root.getContentHandler();`. edited the main question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)? Your code can look like

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("body").first().children();
//or only `<p>` elements
//Elements elements = doc.select("p"); 
for (Element el : elements)
    System.out.println("element: "+el);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your grabbing the HTML.  If its a local file then you can load it directly into Jsoup.  If you have to fetch it from some URL then I normally use Apache's HttpClient.  A quick start guide is here: [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html) and does a good job of getting you started.

That will allow you to get the data back doing something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
//
// here you can do things like add parameters used when connecting to the remote site    
//
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Then (as has been suggested by Pshemo) I use Jsoup to parse and extract the data [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
// OR
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(HTML);
Elements elements = doc.select("p");  // p for <p>text</p>
```

Comment: thanks, my html i local file, so if my way didn't work i will go with jsoup